# Python Delete point in a distance of x meters

Tags: python, arcmap, arcpy, point, loop

I took this code from this source [Select maximum number of points more than x meters apart](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21616/select-maximum-number-of-points-more-than-x-meters-apart/21961#21961)

It seems to work for other users, but for me it's an endless loop. I do not understand why, though the code makes sense. The code itself gives me the result I want to get.

Can you help me out of this endless loop:

```py
import arcpy, sys

feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
distance = 500

arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True

#running NEAR analysis - every point gets attribute of a distance to the nearest point 
#in same feature class
arcpy.AddMessage("running first near analysis")
arcpy.Near_analysis(feature, feature)

arcpy.AddMessage("inserting cursor")
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature)
row = cur.next()

arcpy.AddMessage("starting loop")

i=0
while row:
    i+=1
    #fids list will store list of deleted points so if any other point will have 
    #deleted one as the nearest and distance < 150 will not get deleted as this
    #distance is no longer true
    fids = []
    while row:
        if row.NEAR_DIST < distance:
            try:
                #it seems I didn't know if .. in .. at the time ;) such a fun to dig
                #this script up! index throws an exception if element is not in the 
                #list
                fids.index(row.NEAR_FID)
                arcpy.AddMessage("OBJECTID = " + str(row.OBJECTID) + " is listed!")
            except:
                arcpy.AddMessage("deleting OBJECTID = " + str(row.OBJECTID))
                fids.append(row.FID)
                cur.deleteRow(row)
                d = 1
        row = cur.next()
    del cur, row, fids
    try:
        #this idiotic test is to break the loop when no points will have 
        #NEAR_DIST < 150, shameful - I know!
        if d == 1:
            pass
    except:
        sys.exit()
    d = 0
    arcpy.AddMessage("loop iteration " + str(i))

    #and again we go..
    arcpy.Near_analysis(feature, feature)
    cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature)
    row = cur.next()
```

The functional CODE:

```
import arcpy, sys

feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

def nearRoutine():
    #calculate the distances using the current dataset
    arcpy.Near_analysis(feature, feature)

    #iterate through any features which are within the distance
    cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature, '"NEAR_DIST" < 500')
    row1 = cur.next()
    while row1:

        #this point is within the distance of its neighbor, so delete it
        cur.deleteRow(row1)

        #now re-run this routine on the new dataset
        del row1, cur
        cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature, '"NEAR_DIST" < 500')
        row1 = cur.next()
        nearRoutine

#call the recursive routine. It will get progressively faster to run as it will loop through fewer points each time
nearRoutine()
```

Thanks @Stephen Lead

Comment: I really dislike how people use the `while` loop in arcpy and pyqgis to loop features. It is almost never needed and is error prone. Not your fault as you just copied it.  Just a mini rant

Comment: I agree, @NathanW. It doesn't seem as intuitive to me what is going on. You don't need to use .next() in a for loop, and you have a built in counter with enumerate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer - I haven't actually tried to run your code, and have only skimmed it briefly.

But it looks like you have two `while row` loops. Try using two unrelated cursors, eg row1, row2

**EDIT:** here is an approach which uses a recursive script to perform the NEAR. Each time you delete a point, the NEAR function is called again. (I don't have access to an ArcInfo license so I can't actually test it, so perhaps treat this as pseudo-code):

```
import arcpy, sys

feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
distance = 500

def nearRoutine():
    #calculate the distances using the current dataset
    arcpy.Near_analysis(feature, feature)

    #iterate through any features which are within the distance
    cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature, NEAR_DIST < distance)
    row = cur.next()
    while row:

        #this point is within the distance of its neighbor, so delete it
        cur.deleteRow(row)

        #now re-run this routine on the new dataset
        del row, cur
        nearRoutine

#call the recursive routine. It will get progressively faster to run as it will loop through fewer points each time
nearRoutine()
```

Comment: I was thinking that and because feature never gets redefined so it's doing the same thing over and over

Comment: Also, you're deleting the row during the Except clause. It's generally a bad idea to manipulate an array while you're traversing it, since it messes up the indexing (eg, cursor.next is no longer the "next" feature you're expecting)

Comment: I'm sorry I have a very low level programming so your possible solutions are real headache for me.

However I believe that the entities that update because when I power the end of the program, it deleted all the fields exactly as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the [Simplify Line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000010000000) command. This will remove all extraneous vertices within a given distance, aka "delete point in a distance of x meters"

Esri have already done the hard work of writing this function so you might as well use it...

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
#calculate distance in 2 D
def distance(a,b) : 
    return math.sqrt(pow((a[0]-b[0]),2) + pow((a[1]-b[1]),2) )

#
def clean_array2d(array,limit) :
    result = array 
    i = 0 
    while(i < len(array))  : 
        j = 0 
        while(j < len(result)) :  
            if j != i    : 
                dist  = distance(array[i], result[j]) 
                if dist < limit : 
                    result.pop(j)
            j = j + 1 
        i = i + 1 

    return result
dist = 10  
arr = [(974, 34), (975, 34), (976, 34)]

print(clean(arr,dist)) #[(976, 34)]
```